# What is the meaning of "on" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I saw this sentence "I go on a picnic."
What is the meaning of "on" in this sentence.

Comment: I attend a picnic

Comment: @mplungjan Except that "attend" corresponds not to "on" but to "go on".

Comment: So the expression is "go on" with no particular meaning of the loose "on"

Comment: This question cannot be easily answered through the use of a commonly available reference, and should not have been closed as "off-topic."

Comment: @phenry: I disagree - [this ESL site](http://esl.about.com/od/grammarintermediate/a/prepositions_nouns.htm) lists several examples of ***go on xxxx*** in a page which covers several other prepositions (specifically including half-a-dozen ***go for xxxx***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It's asking a bit much to expect a questioner to locate a deep page on a medium-traffic website for an answer--especially considering that both "go" and "on" are stop words at Google and other search engines. Besides, if that page is a commonly available reference, then it should be listed at the [page](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online) we point questioners to when their questions are "off-topic."

Comment: @phenry: Maybe so, but you won't convince me. I just don't think ELU is the right site for people to be asking such basic questions. That's why [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/) was created. If people keep clogging up the [linguists, etymologists, and {serious} English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site with stuff like this, all that'll happen is ELU will go downhill, and ELL will never graduate past beta.

Comment: And if this were actually a site for "linguists, etymologists, and {serious} English language enthusiasts," you might have a point. But it is not that, and it never will be. The users have spoken, and they want a place to ask practical questions that help them understand the subject matter, just like at every other site in the Stack Exchange network. The only people who don't get that, unfortunately, are the ones with the power to close questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here "on" means that you are taking part in the event/experience that's denoted by the word after it.

Similar usages of "on" would be -
I am going on a ride.
She's gone on a fishing trip.
He'd gone on a hunting expedition.